# XACML type for bags

Tags: xml, xacml3

What is the XACML type for a bag?

My condition function is `string-at-least-one-member-of`, and I'm using the `string-bag` function in my request.  What data type `DataType` do I give the `AttributeDesignator` for the bag?

My condition is:

```
     <xacml3:Condition>
        <xacml3:Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-at-least-one-member-of">
           <xacml3:AttributeDesignator AttributeId="test:xacml:1.0:county" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:resource" MustBePresent="false"></xacml3:AttributeDesignator>
           <xacml3:AttributeDesignator AttributeId="test:xacml:1.0:counties" DataType="WHAT SHOULD THIS BE?" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject" MustBePresent="false"></xacml3:AttributeDesignator>
        </xacml3:Apply>
     </xacml3:Condition>
```

and my attribute is

```
    <xacml3:Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject">
        <xacml3:Attribute AttributeId="test:xacml:1.0:counties" IncludeInResult="false">
          <xacml3:Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-bag">
            <xacml3:AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">travis</xacml3:AttributeValue>
            <xacml3:AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">brazoria</xacml3:AttributeValue>
            <xacml3:AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">dallas</xacml3:AttributeValue>
          </xacml3:Apply>
        </xacml3:Attribute>
    </xacml3:Attributes>
```

When I try the request in WSO2, I get

```
<Response xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17">
    <Result>
        <Decision>Deny</Decision>
        <Status>
            <StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:status:ok"/>
        </Status>
    </Result>
</Response>
```

For those interested in the entire files, my request is:

```
<Request xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17" CombinedDecision="false" ReturnPolicyIdList="true">
<Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:resource">
    <Attribute AttributeId="test:xacml:1.0:county" IncludeInResult="true">
        <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">travis</AttributeValue>
    </Attribute>
</Attributes>
<Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject">
    <Attribute AttributeId="test:xacml:1.0:counties" IncludeInResult="true">
      <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-bag">
        <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">travis</AttributeValue>
        <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">brazoria</AttributeValue>
        <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">dallas</AttributeValue>
      </Apply>
    </Attribute>
</Attributes>
</Request>
```

and my policy is:

```
<xacml3:Policy xmlns:xacml3="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17"  PolicyId="county-based-3" RuleCombiningAlgId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:rule-combining-algorithm:first-applicable" Version="1.0">
  <xacml3:Description></xacml3:Description>
  <xacml3:Target></xacml3:Target>
  <xacml3:Rule Effect="Permit" RuleId="http://axiomatics.com/alfa/identifier/stackoverflow.example.checkGroup">
     <xacml3:Description></xacml3:Description>
     <xacml3:Target></xacml3:Target>
     <xacml3:Condition>
        <xacml3:Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-at-least-one-member-of">
           <xacml3:AttributeDesignator AttributeId="test:xacml:1.0:county" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:resource" MustBePresent="false"></xacml3:AttributeDesignator>
           <xacml3:AttributeDesignator AttributeId="test:xacml:1.0:counties" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject" MustBePresent="false"></xacml3:AttributeDesignator>
        </xacml3:Apply>
     </xacml3:Condition>
  </xacml3:Rule> 
  <xacml3:Rule Effect="Deny" RuleId="deny-rule"></xacml3:Rule>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data type should be `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string`:

```
        <xacml3:Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-at-least-one-member-of">
       <xacml3:AttributeDesignator AttributeId="test:xacml:1.0:county" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:resource" MustBePresent="false"></xacml3:AttributeDesignator>
       <xacml3:AttributeDesignator AttributeId="test:xacml:1.0:counties" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject" MustBePresent="false"></xacml3:AttributeDesignator>
    </xacml3:Apply>
```

All attribute designators are in fact bags in XACML. The datatype applies to the entire elements of the bag.

Moreover, you use the function `urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-at-least-one-member-of` which takes 2 bags of String as defined in the XACML 3.0 [specification](http://docs.oasis-open.org/xacml/3.0/xacml-3.0-core-spec-en.html):

> - `urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:x.x:function:type-at-least-one-member-of`
>
> This function SHALL take two arguments that are both a bag of ‘type’
>   values.  It SHALL return a “http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#boolean”.
>   The function SHALL evaluate to "True" if and only if at least one
>   element of the first argument is contained in the second argument as
>   determined by "urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:x.x:function:type-is-in".

The request you sent in is invalid. A `<Request/>` element cannot contain an `<Apply/>` element inside.

Remove `<Apply/>` and you should get the following request:

```
<Request xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17" CombinedDecision="false" ReturnPolicyIdList="true">
<Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:resource">
    <Attribute AttributeId="test:xacml:1.0:county" IncludeInResult="true">
        <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">travis</AttributeValue>
    </Attribute>
</Attributes>
<Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject">
    <Attribute AttributeId="test:xacml:1.0:counties" IncludeInResult="true">

        <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">travis</AttributeValue>
        <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">brazoria</AttributeValue>
        <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">dallas</AttributeValue>

    </Attribute>
</Attributes>
</Request>
```

This is the graphical representation in the Axiomatics Policy Server:

[image: Axiomatics Policy Server - Request Editor]