# WSO2 Identity Server XACML Request results in Indeterminate/Couldn't find AttributeDesignator attribute if more than one policy enabled

Tags: xacml, xacml3, wso2-identity-server

I'm trying to build a policy that would receive from the request a list of attributes and an attribute, check if the single attribute is inside the list and permit based on that. I'm still a newbie, so I might have overlooked something.

What I've come up with is a slightly modified version of [XACML type for bags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24393392/xacml-type-for-bags).

When evaluated with the WSO2 TryIt tool by itself, the result is Permit. Same thing happens if this is the only enabled policy on the server. If I enable other policies it responds with Indeterminate/Couldn't find AttributeDesignator attribute.

The same does not happen when I make requests that hit other policies. Other policies returns the expected results, although none include lists.

Why does it do that and how can I mitigate it?

Policy:

```
<xacml3:Policy xmlns:xacml3="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17"  PolicyId="county-based-3" RuleCombiningAlgId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:rule-combining-algorithm:first-applicable" Version="1.0">
   <xacml3:Description></xacml3:Description>
   <xacml3:Target>
      <xacml3:AnyOf>
         <xacml3:AllOf>
            <xacml3:Match MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal">
               <xacml3:AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">bay</xacml3:AttributeValue>
               <xacml3:AttributeDesignator AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:action:action-id" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:action" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true"></xacml3:AttributeDesignator>
            </xacml3:Match>
         </xacml3:AllOf>
      </xacml3:AnyOf>
   </xacml3:Target>
   <xacml3:Rule Effect="Permit" RuleId="http://axiomatics.com/alfa/identifier/stackoverflow.example.checkGroup">
      <xacml3:Description></xacml3:Description>
      <xacml3:Target></xacml3:Target>
      <xacml3:Condition>
         <xacml3:Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-at-least-one-member-of">
            <xacml3:AttributeDesignator AttributeId="test:xacml:1.0:county" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:resource" MustBePresent="false"></xacml3:AttributeDesignator>
            <xacml3:AttributeDesignator AttributeId="test:xacml:1.0:counties" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject" MustBePresent="false"></xacml3:AttributeDesignator>
         </xacml3:Apply>
      </xacml3:Condition>
   </xacml3:Rule>
   <xacml3:Rule Effect="Deny" RuleId="deny-rule"></xacml3:Rule>
</xacml3:Policy>
```

The request that goes with it:

```
<Request xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17" CombinedDecision="false" ReturnPolicyIdList="true">
<Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:resource">
    <Attribute AttributeId="test:xacml:1.0:county" IncludeInResult="false">
        <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">travis</AttributeValue>
    </Attribute>
</Attributes>
<Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject">
    <Attribute AttributeId="test:xacml:1.0:counties" IncludeInResult="false">

        <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">travis</AttributeValue>
        <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">brazoria</AttributeValue>
        <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">dallas</AttributeValue>

    </Attribute>
</Attributes>
<Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:action">
        <Attribute AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:action:action-id" IncludeInResult="false">
            <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">bay</AttributeValue>
        </Attribute>
    </Attributes>
</Request>
```

Indeterminate response:

```
<Response xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17">
    <Result>
        <Decision>Indeterminate</Decision>
        <Status>
            <StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:status:processing-error"/>
            <StatusMessage>Couldn't find AttributeDesignator attribute</StatusMessage>
        </Status>
    </Result>
</Response>
```

An example Policy and Request that, when enabled, make the server exhibit this problem:

```
<Policy xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17" PolicyId="TestingStuff" RuleCombiningAlgId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:rule-combining-algorithm:deny-overrides" Version="1.0">
    <Target>
        <AnyOf>
            <AllOf>
                <Match MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-regexp-match">
                    <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">creaky</AttributeValue>
                    <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:resource:resource-id" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:resource" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true"/>
                </Match>
            </AllOf>
        </AnyOf>
    </Target>
    <Rule Effect="Permit" RuleId="Stuff">
        <Target>
            <AnyOf>
                <AllOf>
                    <Match MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal">
                        <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">grease</AttributeValue>
                        <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:action:action-id" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:action" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true"/>
                    </Match>
                </AllOf>
                <AllOf>
                    <Match MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal">
                        <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">break</AttributeValue>
                        <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:action:action-id" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:action" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true"/>
                    </Match>
                </AllOf>
            </AnyOf>
        </Target>
        <Condition>
            <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:or">
                <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal">
                    <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-one-and-only">
                        <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject:subject-id" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true"/>
                    </Apply>
                    <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">someHuman</AttributeValue>
                </Apply>
                <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal">
                    <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-one-and-only">
                        <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject:subject-id" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true"/>
                    </Apply>
                    <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Martin</AttributeValue>
                </Apply>
            </Apply>
        </Condition>
        <AdviceExpressions>
            <AdviceExpression AdviceId="role" AppliesTo="Permit">
                <AttributeAssignmentExpression AttributeId="role">
                    <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">mechanic</AttributeValue>
                </AttributeAssignmentExpression>
            </AdviceExpression>
        </AdviceExpressions>
    </Rule>
</Policy>
```

The request:

```
<Request xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17" CombinedDecision="false" ReturnPolicyIdList="false">
    <Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:action">
        <Attribute AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:action:action-id" IncludeInResult="false">
            <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">grease</AttributeValue>
        </Attribute>
    </Attributes>
    <Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject">
        <Attribute AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject:subject-id" IncludeInResult="false">
            <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Martin</AttributeValue>
        </Attribute>
    </Attributes>
    <Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:resource">
        <Attribute AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:resource:resource-id" IncludeInResult="false">
            <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">creaky</AttributeValue>
        </Attribute>
    </Attributes>
</Request>
```

Answer (score 1):

That is weird indeed. If I import the first policy into [Axiomatics](http://www.axiomatics.com/) policy authoring tool (disclaimer: I work for Axiomatics) and use the simulation feature, I get the results as expected.

The simulation shows that the evaluation follows the path as shown:

[image]

I am not sure why you are seeing the behaviour you described, at your side. One thing I am not sure of is what you meant when you said "If I enable other policies" Do you reference this second policy from within the first?

Comment: AFAIK I'm not referencing any other policy from the original one. What I mean about enabling other policies is that in WSO2 you have a way to enable/disable policies on the PDP after publishing them.  [WSO2 enable disable](http://i.imgur.com/Fvh3kRl.png). 

If I enable other policies it seems like they conflict with this one, although I see nothing they could conflict with. The targets are different and all the attributes are also different.

Comment: Haa, ok. I won't be able to check that behaviour on my side, sorry!

Comment: Axiomatics doesn't have a way of pushing more than one policy on the PDP?

Comment: In Axiomatics, you can push as many policies as you like to the PDP. The behavior is that there is a root policy and all other policies (there could be hundreds) are referenced from the root policy.

Comment: As David mentioned, policy deployment on Axiomatics PDP has a a main (entrypoint) policyset that can then contain multiple policies (or policysets). In this case, if I add a main policyset that contains the two different policies you have mentioned, as long as the policy combining algorithm is set correctly, the behavior is as expected.

Comment: I have added another policy that does something akin to the first one, and it seems to work... I think that the WSO2 PDP works the same way, just it doesn't make it obvious that you have a root policyset.